# Strange UAC crash, can't shut down pc without signing out first

Tags: windows, shutdown, uac, windows-10-v1909

When I try to power off my pc (Running Windows 10 Pro 1909) it just does nothing, but it also seems that it's somehow messing up UAC. How I found this out was by trying to launch something, the UAC prompt just doesn't open and as a result the application doesn't open either. Same goes for alt+ctrl+del menu, though task manager works just fine if i start it through the taskbar. Shutdown command does not work. If I forcefully log myself off with task manager, I'm just left with a black screen and am forced to manually reboot. Never encountered this problem and it's very strange. 
Though I found a workaround - sign out first, then turn off. That works but it's still a problem that needs to be corrected. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0):

First try the Windows 10 initial repair sequence. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run:

1. dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image   /restorehealth  followed by
2. sfc /scannow

Restart when these are both complete and test.

If the above fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Windows 10 Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Use the second link, download, and run in place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, though they didn't fix my problem. I'll be getting a new SSD soon so I'll just reinstall Windows at this point.